# How to split date string using Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm retrieving text value of last updated time from application.

Output looks like this:

```
03/02/2016 5:40:78
```

Time is dynamically changing. By using "get text" I retrieve last updated time and outputting to console.

I want to split data.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What language are you using c#? read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` function to achieve same. As you can observe there is a space between your Date and Time

```
String[] DateTime = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Your Locator")).getText().split(" ");

String Date = DateTime[0];
String Time = DateTime[1];
System.out.println(Date);
System.out.println(Time);
```